# How to use javascript to include struts html tag?

Tags: javascript, struts, struts-1, struts-html

I have a check box and a text box.
I have used struts tags  and

Now i need to validate that if the check box is checked, i should gray out (disable) the text box. If it is unchecked the text box shold take phone numbers.

I did lik this, i called a java script on click of check box and did a innerHtml based on wheather checkbox ix checked or not.

var status_check=document.getElementById("line1Checked").checked;
     if(status_check==true){
     document.getElementById("line1").readonly="true";
     }
     else{
     document.getElementById("line1").readonly="false";
     }

I shud make the text box readonly if the check box is selected.
This is how the text box is defiened,

Please suggest..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK - now it's easier to understand - thanks. 1. make sure that use the styleId - attribute within your  for the input-field. To set this input field readonly your javascript code should do:

`document.getElementById("line1").setAttribute("readonly","true");`

hope that helps

Comment: i got my answer..
var status_check=document.getElementById("line1Checked").checked; if(status_check==true){ document.getElementById("line1").readOnly="true"; } else{ document.getElementById("line1").readOnly="false"; }

Comment: All the struts tags will be converted to html tags. so we can use this one

Answer (score 0):

HI DJ,

do you get an error message for your 2nd javascript snippset? Also could post a little bit more code. From these few lines it's hard to see if text will be " or undefined.
Anyway if you disable the textarea take into account that the input may not be posted.

Comment: I have edited the question. Please check it and suggest me the solution.