# text box displays when user select "Other" how to assign the value and retain the value when refresh the page

Tags: java, jsp, struts

have a dropdown where i have set of account numbers and an option of "Other". user can select any account or they can user "Other" option to enter a new account. I have the code like this:

```
      <td>1. Member Account Number<span class="bodyCopy"><font color="#ff0000"> * </font></span>: 
        <html:select name="DataForm" property="accountNumber"  styleClass="formContent"  style="width:80px" onchange="toggleField(this.value);">
         <html:options collection="<%= WorkConstants.TEST1 %>" property="value" labelProperty="label" styleClass="formContent"/>
         <option value="Other">Other </option> 
          </html:select>
         <input type="text" id="Other" value="accountNumber" name="accountNumber" style="display:none;" maxlength="9" size="9" >    
        </td>
```

--- Togglefield function is as below

```
       <script type="text/javascript">
     function toggleField(value) 
    {var a = document.getElementById('Other');
    (value == 'Other')? a.style.display = 'block' : a.style.display = 'none';}
```

My question is,
1) when I select other, the text box displays- good. But how to assign the value to accountNumber ? when I click submit, it is not recognizing getting invalid account number. 
2) When the page refreshes with validation errors, how do I retain value "other" and the text box with the number that is entered? appreciate your input on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mixing html fields and struts fields.  I think for your input field you need to use:

```
<html:text property="accountNumber" />
```

Comment: i can use <html:text. but how can i give id="Other" to hide/show the text box based upon the selection ? is there any workaround ?

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2475296/how-to-use-javascript-to-include-struts-html-tag I think it's trying to do something similar.  I think you need to use styleId within the html:text tag.  I don't have a struts environment currently set up, so I can't easily test this out.  Give it a try though to see if it will work.